# How to download a file from a url and store it in an azure blob storage container

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, webclient, azure-cli

Just wondering if it is possible to do the following?

I have a file from a kudu webapp that I want to download and store as a zip file in a blob storage, I can get it to download to a local machine, but I can't get it to copy directly from the url to blob storage.

Any ideas if this can be done, here is what I have so far

````
$Global:zip = "https://"+"$storageName"+".blob.core.windows.net/"+"$containname"+"/"+"$zipfile"
#generate token with Azure Account. 
$azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$context =Get-AzContext
$profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azProfile) -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Debug ("Getting access token for tenant" + $currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId)
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($context.Subscription.TenantId)
$token.AccessToken 
$kuduApiAuthorisationToken = 'Bearer {0}' -f $token.AccessToken


    if ($slotName -eq ""){
        $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"
    }
    else{
        $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName`-$slotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"
    }
    $virtualPath = $kuduApiUrl.Replace(".scm.azurewebsites.", ".azurewebsites.").Replace("/api/zip/site/wwwroot", "")
    Write-Host " Downloading File from WebApp. Source: '$kuduApiUrl'. Target: '$zip'..." -ForegroundColor DarkGray

#Call zip Rest API to download the Zip file from webapp. 
`
$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Headers.Add('Authorization', $kuduApiAuthorisationToken)
$WebClient.Headers.Add('ContentType', 'multipart/form-data')

$SasToken = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Name $storageName -Permission "write" -context $StorageContext.context
$StContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageName -SasToken $SasToken
# Download via Azure PowerShell
$FileName = $kuduApiUrl
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $FileName -Container $ContainName -Destination $zip -Context $StContext
#$WebClient.DownloadFile($kuduApiUrl, $Store)```
````

Answer (score 0):

> I have a file from a kudu web app that I want to download and store as a zip file in a blob storage

To upload a file to Azure blob storage you need to use **`Set-AzStorageBlobContent`** command.

The above command helps us to upload files from local to Azure blob storage.

You can use the below command to store a zip in blob storage from the Kudu web app.

**Command:**

```
$webAppName = "<your-web-app-name>"
$slotName = "<your-slot-name>"
$zipfile = "<your-zip-file-name>"
$storageName = "<your-storage-account-name>"
$containname = "<your-container-name>"
$zip = "<your-zip-file-path>"

# Generate token with Azure Account
$azProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
$context = Get-AzContext
$profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azProfile) -ErrorAction Stop
$token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($context.Subscription.TenantId)
$kuduApiAuthorisationToken = 'Bearer {0}' -f $token.AccessToken

# <span class=" active-doc-0" data-doc-items="0">Download file from Kudu web app[1](#doc-pos=0)</span>
if ($slotName -eq ""){
    $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"
}
else{
    $kuduApiUrl = "https://$webAppName`-$slotName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/"
}

$virtualPath = $kuduApiUrl.Replace(".scm.azurewebsites.", ".azurewebsites.").Replace("/api/zip/site/wwwroot", "")
Write-Host "Downloading file from WebApp. Source: '$kuduApiUrl'. Target: '$zip'..." -ForegroundColor DarkGray

$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$WebClient.Headers.Add('Authorization', $kuduApiAuthorisationToken)
$WebClient.Headers.Add('ContentType', 'multipart/form-data')

# Download file to local machine
$WebClient.DownloadFile($kuduApiUrl, $zipfile)

# <span class=" active-doc-0" data-doc-items="0">Upload file to Azure Blob Storage[1](#doc-pos=0)</span>
$StContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageName  -UseConnectedAccount 
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $zipfile -Container $containname -Blob sample.zip -Context $StContext
```

**Output:**

The above command was executed successfully and stored a zip file in Azure blob storage.

```
Downloading file from WebApp. Source: 'https://<webappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/'. Target: 'https://storagename.
blob.core.windows.net/test/sample.zip'...


   AccountName: venkat123, ContainerName: test

Name                 BlobType  Length          ContentType                    LastModified         AccessTier SnapshotTime              
----                 --------  ------          -----------                    ------------         ---------- ------------              
sample.zip           BlockBlob 13034           application/octet-stream       2023-05-18 05:23:37Z Hot
```

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Set-AzureStorageBlobContent (Azure.Storage) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0)

Comment: @ventatesan, I understand this and it is what my code does, but I don't want to download it to a local machine I want the zip file placed in a storage container, which then negates the need for a local machine and this can then be ran through the cli to automate the process.